# APEX Trigger update picklist on child object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, picklist

I am trying to do something simple (I hope).
I have 2x objects: Contact and Career_Path__c
Contact has one field: Currency__c (picklist)
Career_Path__c has one field: Next_Currency__c (picklist)
hese two objects are related via a loopup relationship from Career_Path__c up to Contact

I am trying to update the Next_Currency__c field every time a new Career_Path__c record is created. This does not seem to work. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
trigger Trigger_dynPicklist_2 on Contact (after insert) {    

Map<Id, String> contactIdToCareerPathMap = new Map<Id, String>();

for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
    if (String.isNotBlank(c.Id)) {
    //System.debug('El contacto tiene id: '+c.Id);
    contactIdToCareerPathMap.put(c.Id, c.Currency__c);
    }
}

List<Career_Path__c> careerPathToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Next_Currency__c, Contact__c
                                                FROM Career_Path__c
                                                WHERE Contact__c IN :contactIdToCareerPathMap.keySet()
                                          ];

if(careerPathToUpdate.size() > 0){
    //System.debug('Tiene hijos');
    for (Career_Path__c career : careerPathToUpdate) {
        //System.debug('hijos: '+ career.id);
        career.Next_Currency__c = contactIdToCareerPathMap.get(career.Contact__c);
    }
    update careerPathToUpdate;
}
```

}

Comment: what do your debug statements tell you? Are you getting results from your query? You can [edit] your question to add in more info on any debugging you may have done.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set trigger on Contact when you actually need to set it on Career_Path__c SObject. Your code should look something like this to achieve Next_Currency__c auto-populated from related Contact Currency__c (also take a note that trigger will now be BEFORE insert, so you do not need to update record again):

```
trigger Trigger_dynPicklist_2 on Career_Path__c (before insert) {
    Set<Id> relatedContactsIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Career_Path__c path : Trigger.new) {
        if (path.Contact__c != null) {
            relatedContactsIds.add(path.Contact__c);
        }
    }
    
    Map<Id, Contact> relatedContactsMap = [SELECT Id, Currency__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :relatedContactsIds AND Currency__c != NULL];

    for (Career_Path__c path : Trigger.new) {
        if (path.Contact__c != null && relatedContactsMap.containsKey(path.Contact__c)) {
            path.Next_Currency__c = relatedContactsMap.get(path.Contact__c).Currency__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note, that when Contact is just created (and you are in trigger on insert), it cannot have related Career_Path__c objects.